# EAS update not loading assets

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, expo

I have updated my app using eas update last week and it worked fine, this week, using the same project with the same packages, I try to run eas update again, but this time at the end of exporting files and uploading files, I get a warning like error

```
i 47 iOS assets, 47 Android assets (maximum: 2000 total per update). Learn more about asset limits.: https://expo.fyi/eas-update-asset-limits
git exited with non-zero code: 128
```

[image]

I need to know what is needed here, please. Please let me know if you need more information on this.